# Странное поведение netfilter

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, iptables

Наткнулся на непонятное поведение netfilter. Допустим, есть 4 сервера на centos6 настроенные абсюлютно аналогично. Первые два отсылают логи на третий, на третьем настроен `postrouting` (см. правила ниже) на четвёртый, четвёртый же просто коллекционирует их (на нём не настроен netfilter).

Странность заключается в том, что я вижу трафик `syslog` от первого (10.0.0.1) сервера по всей цепочке, но в то же время трафик второго (10.0.0.2) в полном объёме есть на третьем (192.168.0.5) сервере с `postrouting`, но он не перенаправляет его на четвёртый (192.168.0.6) и в `iptables -nvL -t nat` счётчики не инкрементируются на нём. Если быть точным, то перенаправляет только какие-то определённые сообщения `syslog` - `auth.info` , а, например, `user.info` перенаправлять не хочет. Но ведь это же бред, netfilter не занимается разбором уровня логгирования.

iptables-save третьего

```
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    *mangle
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [113944481:33094585962]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [36662612:8817293771]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [77275595:24276061507]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [20980539:14824196963]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [98253790:39099771398]
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [77275534:24276051904]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [20980520:14824192939]
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 30 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/19 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
    -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [1068499:66961971]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [653110:39701523]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [2512:193995]
    -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/32 -d 192.168.0.5/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.6:514 
    -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.20/32 -d 192.168.0.5/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.6:514 
    -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.2/32 -d 192.168.0.5/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.6:514 
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
    *raw
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [113944408:33094574090]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [20980533:14824201419]
    -A PREROUTING -p dccp -j NOTRACK 
    -A OUTPUT -p dccp -j NOTRACK 
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Fri Apr 27 14:31:48 2018
```

Примеры дампов с третьего сервера
[От первого к третьему]

```
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
    14:43:13.467236 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 112
    14:43:13.467249 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.6.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 112
    14:43:13.467252 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.6.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 112
    14:43:13.523133 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 89
    14:43:13.523133 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 89
    14:43:13.523142 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.6.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 89
    14:43:13.523144 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.6.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 89
    14:43:13.523317 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 79
    14:43:13.523317 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 79
    14:43:13.523326 IP 10.0.0.1.15598 > 192.168.0.6.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 79
```

[От второго к третьему]

```
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
    14:43:25.861971 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 112
    14:43:25.876292 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 134
    14:43:25.876292 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 134
    14:43:25.876512 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 90
    14:43:25.876512 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 90
    14:43:25.876680 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 78
    14:43:25.876680 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 78
    14:43:25.876857 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 85
    14:43:25.876857 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 85
    14:43:25.876993 IP 10.0.0.2.18469 > 192.168.0.5.514: SYSLOG user.info, length: 98
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не ответ на вопрос, а некоторые соображения.

**Первое**.

Очень трудно понимать и траблшутить сетевые вопросы не имея четкого представления о сетевой инфраструктуре. Сеть любит четкую схему. Пытаться понять из свободного повествования и полотен правил iptables-а, что там, куда и зачем - тяжело. Сомневаюсь, что кто-то будет сидеть, рисовать на бумажке хосты, айпишники, додумывать сетевое окружение и т.д.

Было бы гораздо легче, чтобы возникало меньше (либо вообще не возникало) дополнительных вопросов.

Для этого неплохо описать схему в виде:

```
host1 - ip.address.0.1
host2 - ip.address.0.2
и т.д.
Сети такие-то, маски такие-то, шлюзы такие-то.
```

Это описание уже даст вполне конкретное представление об инфраструктуре.

Но это так, к слову.

**Второе**.

Если ваша задача именно в сборе сислогов на конечном (четветром) хосте, а не практика по iptables, то я бы тут вообще не трогал сетевую часть, и "низкоуровневый" роутинг.

Всё это можно решить стандартным rsyslog-ом.

Первые два хоста отправляют логи в rsyslog третьего хоста, который в свою очередь выступает в качестве прокси, перенаправляя их в rsyslog четвертого хоста.

На третьем хосте в конфиге rsyslog надо прописать соответствующее правило, типа:

```
if $fromhost-ip=='a.b.c.d' then forward_to_another_host
```

Comment: По какой-то необъяснимой причине, третий сервер наутро передумал и начал роутить весь трафик от второго сервера... какой-то полтергейст.

Comment: @whoknow тогда можете смело удалять свой вопрос, т.к. он теперь не имеет смысла.